# Parent LenZ is not a sum of Children LenZ?

Tags: sketchup

Alright, i'm creating a Sketchup model but i'm confused. The parent component is not taking it's children properties correctly. Is this normal?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I fixed it! In case other people stumble on this problem: In every child component add the attribute you want to let the parent to Sum up.. (in my case i forgot to add the attribute "LenZ" to a component at the bottom of the list). If you do not add them the parent will not sum them.